# I have a Rails app using React posting to my db using an ajax call. How do I handle the redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs, crud

So I have my Rails app trying to submit a cohort to the database. I can get it to post to the database but I do not know how to handle the redirect.

```
var NewCohort = React.createClass ({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {name:'',description:''}
  },
  handleNameChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({name:e.target.value})
  },
  handleDescriptionChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({description:e.target.value})
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    var that = this
    $.ajax({
      url: '/cohorts',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        name: that.state.name,
        description: that.state.description
      },
      success: function(data, success, xhr) {
        console.log(data)
      }
    })
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h3>Create a new cohort</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleNameChange}/>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.description} onChange={this.handleDescriptionChange}/>
          <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

Is my ajax call which I send to my controller which has

```
def create
    @cohort = Cohort.create(name: params[:name], description: params[:description])
    render component: 'ShowCohort', props: { cohort: @cohort }
end
```

Which in my ajax success function, the data is the new React html code. How to I actually redirect the the page?

This is my React component to render

```
var ShowCohort = React.createClass ({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h3>Hello {this.props.cohort.name}</h3>
        <p>{this.props.cohort.description}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: What kind of redirect do you mean here? A traditional browser redirect which will fetch a whole new page from the server and render it in the browser to replace the current page? Or do you want your React app to have it's own routing and urls, managed with (probably) `react-router`?

Comment: Yeah I realized I was using React wrong. I wanted to redirect and this is not the way to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ajax. Just use a regular form.

Answer (score 0):

this should be like this

```
success: function(data, success, xhr) {
        window.location.href = "redirect_url"; 
      }
```

you can pass it as json as well like this in your controller

```
render json: {"redirect":true,"redirect_url": apps_path}, status:200

success: function(data, success, xhr) {
        window.location.href = data.redirect_url;
      }
```